# Angular route navigation in different components

Tags: angular, components

I am doing a project in angular and I am still new in this. Would like to ask your help in what i am doing wrong here.

1 - Have a component header definition using router, with routerlink for navigation
[image]

When I add the component in app.component.html is fine. Component header is added and I can navigate with  any problem
app-headers></app-headers

However I would like to use the header in another component called datosB.
when added, header is load but the links does not work.

Any help would great. thanks

---

### codes

headers.component.html

```
<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark sticky-top shado">
   <a routerLink='/'  class="navbar-brand" (click)="onClick()" >
      <img [src]=logo alt="Logo" style="width:40px;">
         {{ logoName }}
   </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> </span> 
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
     <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 nav-justified" >
        <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let nav of navbars" (click)="onClick()"  >
           <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]=nav.routerlink>
              {{ nav.name }}
           </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

headers.component.ts

```
export class HeadersComponent implements OnInit {
  navbars = [{ name : 'Datos Generales',     routerlink : 'datosgenerales'},
             { name : 'Plan de  Enseñanza',  routerlink : 'planensenanza'},
             { name : 'Plan de Aprendizaje', routerlink : 'planaprendizaje'},
             { name : 'Plan Tutorial',       routerlink : '#'},
             { name : 'Bibliografia',        routerlink : '#'}];
  checkHome = "";
  @Output() signInEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

constructor(private route: Router ) {
   }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-headers></app-headers>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

datos-generales.components.html

```
<app-headers></app-headers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.component.html

```html
<app-headers></app-headers>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And pages load from routing. Not need app-header inject into all page. ;)

*Since you didn't share program code, that's all I could add.*

Comment: Hi,
I have updated the question with the code reference. So in my app.component.html I have exactly how you wrote in above comment but when calling from another component  doesnt work

Comment: Read: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description - absolute: `/bar/foo` - relative: `../` or `./baz` or `../baz`

Comment: thanks Numichi, that helped to understand the mechanism